# Extract month from GA date in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to translate a Legacy SQL query into Standard SQL. My issue is replacing MONTH() with a suitable function in Standard. I read the docs and EXTRACT() seems to be the solution, but I think the date field in BigQuery being a string is stopping this from working correctly.

Here is my Legacy code:

```
SELECT month(date) AS Mon, hits.eventInfo.eventAction, ROUND(AVG(hits.product.productPrice/1000000),2) AS avg_price
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxx.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "Ecommerce"
AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "Add to Basket PDP"
OR hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "Add to Basket PLP"
GROUP BY Mon_of_year, hits.eventInfo.eventAction
```

Here is my Standard code where I have tried to resolve this:

```
SELECT extract(YEAR from PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d',date)) AS Mon, hits.eventInfo.eventAction, ROUND(AVG(hits_product.productPrice/1000000),2) AS avg_price
FROM 
`xxx.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits.product) AS hits_product
WHERE
  parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
    _table_suffix) BETWEEN DATE_sub(CURRENT_DATE(),
    interval 7 day)
  AND DATE_sub(CURRENT_DATE(),
    interval 1 day)
AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "Ecommerce"
AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "Add to Basket PDP"
OR hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "Add to Basket PLP"
GROUP BY mon, hits.eventInfo.eventAction
```

But this is giving me the error:
`Error: Failed to parse input string "20170304"`

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you were close, but you need to use a capital `Y` instead of lowercase `y` for the year part, i.e.:

```
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date)
```

If you want to get the month number, you can use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ...)` or if you want simply to truncate the date to a month boundary, you can use `DATE_TRUNC(..., MONTH)`.

Comment: Elliot, using the code with a capital Y is working, but my month column is showing numbers from 1 to 10 when running for the last 7 days, when I'd expect to see only 1 and 12 - any ideas whats happening?

Comment: What are the corresponding `date` strings that produce these values?

Comment: And that should have a corresponding month of 1 in the results, right? I'm hoping for an example of a date that results in a month other than 1 or 12.